# Changing to end game screen in libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

When my game finishes, i'm trying to change the screen to the end game screen, but instead of doing so, it simply flashes the current game screen.

I belive it is clearing the stage, but then drawing it again without moving to the next screen? As though its still looping the render call.

Can you advise on how to switch screen properly.

```
   @Override
public void render(float v) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    if (state == gamestate.PAUSED) {
        // draw pause screen
    }
    else if (state == gamestate.GAMEOVER || score <= 0) {
        game.setScreen(new endGameScreen(game, score));
        stage.clear();
        return;
    }
    else {
        player.update();

        stage.draw();
        batch.begin();
        mBtn.setPosition((cam.position.x - (Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2)) + 10, (cam.position.y - (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2)) + 10);
        pBtn.setPosition((cam.position.x + (Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2)) - pauseWidth, (cam.position.y - (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2)) + 10);

        batch.draw(player.getCurrentFrame(), player.getPosition().x, player.getPosition().y);

        cam.position.set(player.getPosition().x, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2, 0);
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
        cam.update();

        batch.end();

        if(player.getPosition().x >= finishLine.getX()) {
            System.out.println("End Game!!!");
            endGame();
        }
    }
}
```

Okay, so the full code for the render method is now up. I moved the setting of the input processor to the `show()` method.

This problem could be because the method of `game.setScreen` is in the render method, but i'm not sure how I could implement this in the show method, as it happens when the actor reaches a certain location, so I can't listen out for an input touch or anything.

End Game Screen

```
public class endGameScreen implements Screen {

int score = 0;
String scoreTxt = "";
Stage stage;
SpriteBatch batch;
BitmapFont font;
Game game;

public endGameScreen(Game game, int score){
    this.score = score;
    this.game = game;
}

@Override
public void render(float v) {
    batch.begin();
    font.setColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    font.draw(batch, scoreTxt, 25, 100);
    batch.end();
}

@Override
public void show() {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("font.fnt"));
    stage = new Stage(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight(),true);
}
```

Comment: Not enough of your code to see the problem.

Comment: Why are you setting your inputProcessor on every render call? Doesn't it suffice if you do so when showing the screen?

Have you tested you ever get to the part where it's told to go to the EndGameScreen?

Generally, I don't know if it's such a good practice to do all this checking in your render loop. Just try to do this event-based... whenever you reach the point where you change your game state to game-over, just call the setScreen() method. Or as soon as you recognize a game pause, show the stage where your Pause screen is on. I don't think there's the need to check in every render call...

Comment: Ok ill move that. Yes it does get to that point because i can see gamestate changing.

Comment: Is there any more code outside that last `else` block in the function? Maybe there's another line there that calls `game.setScreen()`... Even if you don't see anything suspicious there, adding `return;` in the `else if` block might be worth a try.

Comment: What do you mean with `it simply flashes the current game screen`? - Are you perhaps setting the screen back to the game screen from within the EndGameScreen? This could result in a flashing of the screen...

Comment: Adding a return didn't help.
@Balder it just shows the game screen, but flashes as though it's rendering then drawing a blank screen, then rendering again every second, really fast. End game code above, no calls back to the game screen.

Comment: @MPeti all the code is there now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very likely caused by the lack of screen clearing in the end game screen. From my experience this results in undefined behavior, working okay on desktop and some phones while it gets crazy yellowish whiteish flashy on others. You still see the previous screen because you don't remove it from the device's hardware screen by clearing.

So just add the glClear line like in the other class.